# Design pattern - Is this a good way to use the command pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a java class `SearchFilterWebPage` which represents a web page for an online shopping website. All of its (filter) methods allow you to set a filter, just like you would on a real shopping website. For example `enterPriceRange(min, max), selectBrandsFilter(String...brands), and selectFreeShippingOnlyFilter()`. **The below code is very simple and only prints messages.**

I made a function `applyMultipleFilters(FilterCommand [] functions)` which allows you to call any number of filter functions of `SearchFilterWebPage` class. Each filter function is represented by an instance of `FilterCommand`, i.e. the command pattern. For example, `enterPriceRange(min, max), and  selectBrandsFilter(String...brands)` are represented by `EnterPriceRangeFilter and SelectBrandsFilter` classes respectively.

Basically, I made a class to represent each filter function. Can someone please tell me if this is a good idea ? Is there any other way besides reflection and the command pattern to implement `applyMultipleFilters(...)` ?

**Class with main method :**

```
public class SearchFilterWebPage {

    public void enterPriceRangeFilter(int min, int max){
        System.out.println("enterPriceRangeFilter");
    }

    public void selectBrandsFilter(String...brands){
        System.out.println("selectBrandsFilter");
    }

    public void selectFreeShippingOnlyFilter(){
        System.out.println("selectFreeShippingOnlyFilter");
    }

    //NOTE - Add 5 or more functions like the above ones !!!

    //MAIN METHOD
    public static void main(String [] main){
        SearchFilterWebPage search = new SearchFilterWebPage();

        FilterCommand [] filters = {
                new EnterPriceRangeFilter(search, 50, 100),
                new SelectBrandsFilter(search, "Adidash", "Nikki", "Pooma")
        };
        search.applyMultipleFilters(filters);
    }

    public void applyMultipleFilters(FilterCommand [] functions){
        for(FilterCommand fun : functions){
            fun.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> EXECUTING : enterPriceRangeFilter
>>> EXECUTING : selectBrandsFilter
```

**Supporting code:**

*Command:*

```
   public interface FilterCommand {
       void execute();
   }
```

*Filter:*

```
   public class EnterPriceRangeFilter implements FilterCommand {
       private final int min;
       private final int max;
       private final SearchFilterWebPage search;

       public EnterPriceRangeFilter(SearchFilterWebPage search, int min, int max) {
           this.search = search;
           this.min = min;
           this.max = max;
       }

       @Override
       public void execute() {
           //Use min, max.
           System.out.print(">>> EXECUTING : " );
           search.enterPriceRangeFilter(min, max);
       }
   }
```

*Filter:*

```
   public class SelectBrandsFilter implements FilterCommand {
       private final String [] brands;
       private final SearchFilterWebPage search;

       public SelectBrandsFilter(SearchFilterWebPage search, String...brands) {
           this.search = search;
           this.brands = brands;
       }

       @Override
       public void execute() {
           //Use brands.
           System.out.print(">>> EXECUTING : ");
           search.selectBrandsFilter(brands);
       }
   }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Suppose that there are many tests/functions which could use different combinations of filters. But, some of these tests/functions use the exact same set of filters. So, I thought of creating combinations of filters which could be reused in different tests/functions. There are two possible solutions to create such combinations that I can think of at the moment.

**Solution 1** - Create a FilterChoices class which will provide all the filtering data to the  SearchFilterWebPage. FilterChoices can be a simple POJO with getters and setters. We could use the builder pattern to build this.
The minor problem is that applyMultipleFilters(...) function will need to do multiple checks to see which all filters have been set in FilterChoices and call the appropriate filter functions.

**Solution 2** - Use the command pattern as mentioned in this post. Unfortunately, we end up creating a lot of code (even if simple) just to avoid checking for which filter functions to call.

Comment: I like that idea. Simple enough and seems to work for me To propose better solution we would know more requirements. What fits now perfectly does not alway fit in the future :)

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga - Actually, the filter functions use selenium web driver to interact with filters in the web page, instead of just printing stuff. I did not show that code on purpose to make the example simple to understand.

Comment: Yeah, I got that you simplified that. For general case the solution you proposed should work IMHO

Comment: Please have a look at Builder design Pattern. You can create the filter object using builder pattern and set each kind of filter using setters.

Comment: @James - With builder pattern, applyMultipleFilters(...) would have to check which all settings have been provided and call filter functions only the settings which are provided. For example, call the enterPriceRange(...) only if minPrice and maxPrice of builder object have been set to non null value. We will have so many null/empty checks which is what I wanted to avoid. Does that make sense ?

Comment: It seems like each filter would make sense implemented as a [`Predicate<SearchFilterWebPage>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html). But ultimately the question is opinion based.

Comment: @bhargav-rao   Given that it is a webApp, as in when the user sets some parameter the builder method shold be called. 
->user sets brand filter 
->  filter = filter.setBrand().build(); 
->user set price range  
-> filter= filter.setPrice().build() 

And finally when user does submit , use the  filter build object